# No qualifying bean of type [com.comcast.activation.message.interfaces.MessageChannels] found for dependency:

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I have a spring boot application that simply sends messages to a kafka topic. The code looks like this.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/ActivationQueueService")
public class ActivationQueueController {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(ActivationQueueController.class);

@Autowired
SpringCloudStreamClient producer;

@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setValidator(new ActivationDataInfoValidator());
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/sendMessage", headers = "Accept=application/json", produces = "application/json")
public void sendMessage(@RequestBody  ActivationDataInfo message)
        throws JsonProcessingException {


    LOGGER.debug("Activation Data Request Recieved : " + message.toString());
    if (message != null) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        producer.sendMessagetoKafka(message);
        LOGGER.info("Activation Data Request sent to Kafka : " + message);
    }
}

}
```

Interface :

```
public interface MessageChannels {

   @Output("activationMsgQueue")
    MessageChannel save();
}
```

Producer :

```
@Service
@EnableBinding(MessageChannels.class)
public class SpringCloudStreamClient {


private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(SpringCloudStreamClient.class);

@Autowired MessageChannels msgChannel;

public Object sendMessagetoKafka(ActivationDataInfo msg){
    LOGGER.info("Sending Message : " + msg);
    msgChannel.save().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(msg).build());
    return new String("Success");
}
}
```

This application runs fine as stand alone application. When i create a jar out of this and include it into another spring boot app so that i can use the producer to send message to topic and  run the  spring boot app  i get following exception :

Unable to instantiate SpringCLoudStreamClient., reason being

:        No qualifying bean of type     [com.comcast.activation.message.interfaces.MessageChannels] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.

I get above exception for the below line of code

```
@Autowired SpringCloudStreamClient producer;
```

I have used component scan to ensure the packages in the jar are scanned by the parent spring boot app. After doing this i get the above exception. Enable binding annotation is not doing what its supposed to do,, that is create a implementation of the message channel interface in this scenario. IS this a bug or am i missing something?

Comment: how are you creating the jars? what are your dependencies?

Comment: doing a gradle build generates a jar of the spring boot app.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, `@EnableBinding(MessageChannels.class)` belongs on a configuration not a bean (it is meta-annotated with `@Configuration`). It doesn't seem that it is recognized as such by your second application, which doesn't trigger the proxy generation process. I still see that it is generated as a bean, though, triggered by the `@Service` annotation. A simple way out of this would be to do an `@Import(SpringCloudStreamClient.class)` in your parent application, although the component scan should bring it in.

How's your parent configuration like?